# How to save output image from Scikit image viewer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to store the output of an image processed using Scikit image viewer. Below is my code:

```
import skimage
image1 = skimage.io.imread(fname='shot1.tif', as_gray=True)
viewer = skimage.viewer.ImageViewer(image1)

edges = skimage.feature.canny(
        image=image1,
        sigma=2.0,
        low_threshold=0.1,
        high_threshold=0.2
        )

viewer = skimage.viewer.ImageViewer(edges)
viewer.show()
```

What is the code to store the output from 'viewer.show()' in a file?

Comment: What does `ImageViewer()` return? I couldn't find the return type in the docs quickly. And what format file do you want?

Comment: It shows edges of the input image using the Scikit image viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be this one

```
skimage.io.imsave(fname, edges)
```

you can find more about the parameters you can use here:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#imsave

Comment: This function only creates a file with black background and without any edges.

Answer (score 0):

What is dtype and maximum value of edges?
Try to rescale intensity before saving:

```
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity
edges = rescale_intensity(edges)
skimage.io.imsave(fname, edges)
```

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity